# How to remove iPad support from my app?

Tags: ios, xcode

I created an app with an iPad storyboard, but we've decided not to support iPad to start with.  Do I need to disable this somewhere in my project, or delete it? Can't seem to find any information on editing it after the project has been created.

Comment: Unrelated, but... is there a specific reason you're choosing not to support an iPad?  If you're supporting iPhone... you already have to manage two different aspect ratios...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At a minimum you have to disable support for iPad.  To do that:

Click the target in the project explorer.  In the General Tab there is a section called Deployment info.  For Devices change the selection from Universal to iPhone.

[image: example]

You can then delete the iPad storyboard from the project explorer.

[image: example2]

Comment: Given your edit, for my sanity... deleting the storyboard is optional in terms of what shows up in what app store, right?  Simply switching from universal to iPhone will prevent it from showing up as an iPad app when it goes to app store?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just checked and when you change that setting what actually changes is in the project.pbxproj file from `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = "1,2";` to `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1;`.  When you delete the storyboard, every reference to it is removed from project.pbxproj.  I would be curious to know if it's packaged anyway but never used if you don't delete it.

Comment: So is deleting the storyboard optional? Say if we wanted to develop for the iPad at a later date, should I leave it in there?

Comment: Yes it's optional.  That being said I say delete it so when you're ready for iPad you get that experience creating it from scratch and linking it up (:

Comment: Ha! Yeah, that sounds like fun. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

File Inspector -> Selected Target -> General -> UnCheck

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove storyboard. Here are the steps

1) Remove Main.storyboard file from your project.

2) Add new files with xib for your controller , if it is not added in compiled sources in build phases then add there manually.

3) Remove Main storyboard file base name from plist.

4) Change appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions file and add :

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
just like :

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;

  // Override point for customization after application launch.

  TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
   UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:test];
   self.window.rootViewController = nav;

  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;
  }

If you want to add controller which does not have nib file then just do 
 TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc] init];

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is... overcomplicated, confusing, includes certainly unnecessary steps... and I'm not 100% confident it will actually end up working... the question is about removing iPad support, and you're talking about adding new files...?

Comment: Oh, Heading suggested that you want to remove storyboard, so wrote the steps. sorry.

Comment: The primary point of the question was removing iPad support entirely.  Removing a storyboard seemed optional.

Comment: Ok.As suggested by JuJoDi, you can got to deployment target and click iPhone to make your application support only for iPhone devices